# Perform Numpy operation on matrix of user-defined type items

Tags: python, cryptography, numpy

In my cryptography project, I have to deal with GF(2^8) arithmetic operations. Essentially, the sum operation in this this field (GF(2^8) is normal XOR operation, and the product operation a*b is (a*b) mod m(x). You can skip this mathematics part.

My job is to inverse a matrix 4x4 in GF(2^8). This is not difficult, but it's too tedious to re-implement every matrix operations by hand. I would like to make use of this functionality (inverse a matrix) in numpy, but I was not able to make numpy use my operations between items of a matrix. Say, instead of performing adding between 2 items using '+', I want it to perform XOR whenever '+' operation is used.

I have created a class of my customer type, call GF28. The code can be found below:

```
class GF28(float):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, b):        
        if isinstance(b, GF28):
            return GF28(ops.add(self.value, b.value))
        else:
            return GF28(ops.add(self.value, b))
    __rsub__ = __isub__ = __sub__ = __radd__ = __iadd__ = __add__

    def __mul__(self, b):
        if isinstance(b, GF28):
            return GF28(ops.mul(self.value, b.value))
        else:
            return GF28(ops.mul(self.value, b))
    __rmul__ = __imul__ = __mul__

    def __div__(self, b):
        return self.__mul__(self.inv(b))
    __rdiv__ = __idiv__ = __div__

    def inv(self):
        return GF28(ops.inv(self.value))
    def __float__(self):        
        return self
```

And then I create a matrix of these GF28 items using:

```
a = array([[GF28(10), GF28(20), GF28(30)],
           [GF28(12), GF28(21), GF28(4)],
           [GF28(9), GF28(16), GF28(13)]])
```

It appears that only the float() cast function is being used, the rest is not touched at all.

Please help me to make this operation overriding work. Thanks a lot.

[edit] Performing basic matrix operation is already ok. If somebody could make this work with matrix inversion, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `a` to be of `dtype` `object`:

```
a = np.array([(GF28(10), GF28(20), GF28(30)),
              (GF28(12), GF28(21), GF28(4)),
              (GF28(9), GF28(16), GF28(13))],dtype='object')
```

Then the type of the elements in the array are `GF28`. For example:

```
type(a[0,0])
# <class '__main__.GF28'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works well with normal operations (for example, mat(a)*mat(b)), but when applying inverse operation the result is not what I expected...

Comment: @wakandan: `np.linalg.inv` calls `np.linalg.solve`, which calls lapack routines such as `zgesv` or `dgesv`. These fortran functions expect floats, so I don't think your idea of marrying GF28 objects with numpy is going to work if you are calling `np.linalg.inv`.

Comment: Hi. Hmm so that means these underlying Fortran functions will not operation on my data correctly? Could we somehow hook these underlying functions away to use our implementation? It will still be tedious but at least we don't have to rewrite everything...

Comment: @wakandan: I suspect that would be tough. Perhaps it would be much easier to find a pure Python implementation of matrix inversion. Since Python uses duck-typing, it may work with your GF28 matrices without any changes.

Comment: Could you put the results of these comments into the answer itself? Thanks!